# Advanced editor tracking in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, editing, features, tracking, data-management

Is there a way to track edits which have been made to a feature class in ArcGIS Pro? I.e. a field being auto populated which would give information in regards to what kind of edit has been made, e.g. "[Feature] location has altered" or "[Feature] [Field name] has been altered"

Comment: In addition to Fezters answer below, Audit History, or editing tracking, would require its own table in a dataset and is usually managed at the database level through insert triggers, which is a preference for data being captured into a database, as it abstracts the auditing capability from the application doing the capture. (eg: In the future, it might be automated updates from a batch process).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't anything out of the box that will capture changes to individual fields. [Editor tracking in ArcGIS](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/enable-editor-tracking.htm), when enabled on a feature class will give you the following information:

- Created By
- Created Date
- Last Edited By
- Last Edited Date

If you want something more, you'll probably have to write something bespoke.

It also depends on what your underlying database is. If you are using a file geodatabase, you're probably out of luck. However, if you're using an Enterprise geodatabase, you may be able to leverage the power of the database to create a table with those changes.

SQL Server has [Change Data Capture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). From the documentation:

> Change data capture records insert, update, and delete activity that
> applies to a SQL Server table. This makes the details of the changes
> available in an easily consumed relational format. Column information
> and the metadata that is required to apply the changes to a target
> environment is captured for the modified rows and stored in change
> tables that mirror the column structure of the tracked source tables.
> Table-valued functions are provided to allow systematic access to the
> change data by consumers.

One of the columns that the CDC table has is, `__$update_mask` is a bit mask defined for each captured column, identifying the updating columns.

I think there may be similar functionality in other enterprise geodatabases, such as Oracle.